# Twilio Video - Connect Voice. Not able to have two way communication

Tags: twilio, twilio-video, twilio-programmable-voice

I am trying to connect voice to a video room. I was able to connect it successfully. The phone call was able to receive voice from the room (Which is from my computer) but the room is not able to receive voice from phone. Here is the link I am referring to.

[Twilio Voice Connect](https://www.twilio.com/docs/video/adding-programmable-voice-participants-video-rooms)
https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/connect

Here is my code which tries to connect to the room:

```
var response = new VoiceResponse();
var connect = new Connect();
response.Say("You are now getting connected to a room");
connect.Room("TestCollaborationVoice8_col_63"); //This is my Room unique ID.
response.Append(connect);
return TwiML(response);`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question here: The application calls at participantConnected when someone joins the room. For me it was at UI. I had to update little code to add/receive the tracks.